# WP_Query + random

Tags: wp-query

Is there any way to get this

```
<?php 
$pc = new WP_Query ('category_name=cat1&posts_per_page=5'); 
?>
```

but each time display a RANDOM different batch of 5 ones?

Comment: note that `rand` order is very expensive on the database

Answer (score 41):

Please try this:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name'  => 'cat1',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
);

$pc = new WP_Query( $args );
```

where `'rand'` should give you a random order of your posts.

For more info check out the *Codex* on `WP_Query` *order* parameters [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).